# moment format string that matches Date.prototype.toString

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to detect if a `String` being passed to my function is what `Date.prototype.toString` returns. (I don't have access to the date itself so doing something like _.isDate() is not possible)

```
moment( str ).isValid()  // returns true for an input of 1001
```

So, I need to make it more precise and not sure what the format string is to match this:

> Mon Nov 27 2017 21:49:49 GMT-0600 (CST)

I know I need to do something like:
`moment(string, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS", true).isValid()` but not sure how to get that GMT-0600 (CST) part in a moment format string.

My dirty workaround was to do `_.isNaN( _.parseInt(string) ) && moment(string).isValid()`

Comment: Where does string come from? Better to work with ISO string such as returned by `date.toISOString()` or `date.toJSON()`

Comment: I fear there is no way to parse timezone abreviation (like CST) in momentjs.

Comment: You can't do that easily. The output of *Date.prototype.toString* is entirely implementation dependent, so you need a method that adapts depending on the implementation. You'll need to parse the input string to get the format, then see if it matches the format of the host *Date.prototype.toString*.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reask a similar question since this was not answered.

- [What is JavaScript's default Date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888683/what-is-javascripts-default-date-format/72888921#72888921)

#### Answer: `console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate());`