# What is JavaScript's default Date format?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, default, date-formatting

### What is the name of this format?

```
Wed Jul 06 2022 14:42:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

This format is the default format that is output "Independent of input format" from `new Date()`.

- *source - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp* w3schools explains the format but fails to mention what it's called before getting into other ISO format types.

#### How do you turn a date into that format using Moment.js?

- Example: `2022-07-15T00:00:00.000Z` or `2015-03-25`

```js
console.log(moment(new Date()).toISOString());
// 2022-07-06T19:08:36.670Z

console.log(moment(new Date()).toString());
// Wed Jul 06 2022 15:08:36 GMT-0400

console.log(new Date());
// Wed Jul 06 2022 15:08:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

console.log(new Date().toString());
// Wed Jul 06 2022 15:08:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

You can see that `moment(new Date()).toISOString()` and `moment(new Date()).toString()` **DO NOT** output that same format as the default JS format.

- `moment(new Date()).toString()` is close, but is still missing the `(Eastern Daylight Time)` which is part of the default.

Comment: "*How do you turn a date into that format using Moment.js?*" counter-question - *why* do you need to convert to that format with Moment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Answer:

##### `console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate());`

*That was way harder to find than it should have been.*

```js
console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate());
// Wed Jul 06 2022 15:25:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

console.log(new Date());
// Wed Jul 06 2022 15:25:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

console.log(new Date().toString());
// Wed Jul 06 2022 15:25:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

### Bonus:

```js
console.log(moment(1234, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid());
// true

console.log(1234 instanceof Date)
// false

console.log(new Date() instanceof Date);
// true
```

Comment: `console.log(new Date().toDate());` does not necessary produce the OP format. Consoles are free to convert *Dates* to strings however they like, e.g. the SO console returns a string consistent with *toISOString*, not plain *toString*.

Comment: `.toDate()` just returns a plain JS date object. So `moment(new Date()).toDate()` is basically the same as `new Date()`. There is no reason to go back and forth through a third party library for that - if you have a JS date already, and apparently you all you want to treat it as a JS date, then what's the point of passing it through Moment to do that?

Comment: Yeah that the thing, the date coming in will be in various formats.

Comment: You're only passing in a date object. There aren't "various formats" of date objects. If you mean that you'd be using Moment to parse various different date strings, then that's not at all reflected in the question. If you are *not* parsing different date strings with Moment, then the conversion from a date object to a date object is useless.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry then. Sorry that my questions was not specific enough, I will do better in the future. Thank you for your feedback. ❤️

Answer (score 1):

> What is the name of this format?

It's not ISO, it's a format specified in ECMA-262, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

To convert it to ISO use `date.toISOString()`

Btw. don't use `w3schools.com` this website has major errors

> How do you turn a date into that format using Moment.js?

1. ISO: `moment(new Date()).toISOString()`
2. `2015-03-25`: `moment(new Date()).format('yyyy-MM-dd')`
3. ECMA-262: `moment(new Date()).toDate().toString()`

P.S. I would consider using a different library as moment.js isn't getting updates anymore, but if you don't have a choice it's fine.

Comment: Specifically, [`Date#toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) converts to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Thank you, so that helps a little bit. My second question still persists: I will update my question with more context.